# How to implement file reading and creating into a structure

Tags: c++

I don’t know how to implement reading data and put it into the structure

There is a config.txt file, it stores data like

```
someBigText=ASDSDdasdsa (can be more +1000 simbol)
isOkay=true
myAge=24
```

```cpp
struct Config {
    std::string Name;
    std::string StringValue;
};
```

Comment: The easiest approach is to use `std::getline()` to read the file line by line and then parse individual lines to the name and value.

Comment: where is the "name" and "StringValue" info that you need in the key values you posted from config.txt?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your config is splitted in sections like:

```
[myImportantSection] 
someBigText = "foo tha can be more +1000 simbols" 
isOkay = true 
myAge = 24
```

and assuming you are using boost:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>



boost::property_tree::ptree myPtree;
boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("config.txt", myPtree);
auto text{myPtree.get<std::string>("myImportantSection.someBigText")};
auto isOk{myPtree.get<bool>("myImportantSection.isOkay")};
auto age{myPtree.get<int>("myImportantSection.myAge")};

struct Config
{
    std::string text{};
    bool ok{false};
    int age{0};
};

Config myConfig;

myConfig.text = text;
myConfig.ok = isOk;
myConfig.age = age;
```